# Does Linux tmpfs filesystem need the sync option?

Tags: tmpfs

I'm looking for info about mounting a tmpfs partition and **sync** option.
Sync makes the data beeing dumped onto the disk without beeing saved in cache.
This works with ext4 and other filesystems. I'm wondering is even a tmpfs partition needs the sync option to be specified or it is enabled by default since it is a RAM partition. In my option it would be odd if a ramdisk would be cached in RAM.

`tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,sync,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=0777,size=400M 0 0`

In a tmpfs partition is sync enabled by default?

Comment: `tmpfs` is not backed by any partition in the first place.

Comment: exactly, let's change subject once again ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to search a bit.
According to

> man mount

The *sync* option is relevant only for a limited number of filesystems, not for tmpfs.

So the answer is: It does not matter, since it is ignored by tmpfs.

Answer (score 6):

> Sync makes the data beeing dumped onto the disk without beeing saved in cache

"Standard" Linux manual states:

```
   sync   All I/O to the filesystem should be done synchronously.
          In the case of media with a limited number of write cycles
          (e.g. some flash drives),  sync may cause life-cycle shortening.
```

So it's not about cacheing but rather about durability. *Writing synchronously* doesn't mean there wouldn't be caching (for e. g., writethrough is well-known caching approach which is very different to writeback but both still are cacheing).

> In my option it would be odd if a ramdisk would be cached in RAM.

As explained it doesn't prohibit cacheing but rather prohibits writeback-like behaviour. What would be odd is "durability" for RAM disk though.

Comment: It made a ton of sense on the 2.0 kernel ramdisk implementation, which actually did cache (I know crazy huh).

Comment: probably you misread it. tmpfs isn't block device which RAM-disk is. Also it's not about cache